# How to free the memory of a string returned from Rust in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, rust, ffi

I have these two functions exposed from **Rust**

```
extern crate libc;

use std::mem;
use std::ffi::{CString, CStr};

use libc::c_char;

pub static FFI_LIB_VERSION: &'static str = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"); // '

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rustffi_get_version() -> *const c_char {
    let s = CString::new(FFI_LIB_VERSION).unwrap();
    let p = s.as_ptr();
    mem::forget(s);

    p as *const _
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rustffi_get_version_free(s: *mut c_char) {
    unsafe {
        if s.is_null() {
            return;
        }

        let c_str: &CStr = CStr::from_ptr(s);
        let bytes_len: usize = c_str.to_bytes_with_nul().len();
        let temp_vec: Vec<c_char> = Vec::from_raw_parts(s, bytes_len, bytes_len);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

They are imported by **C#** as below

```
namespace rustFfiLibrary
{
    public class RustFfiApi
    {
        [DllImport("rustffilib.dll", EntryPoint = "rustffi_get_version")]
        public static extern string rustffi_get_version();

        [DllImport("rustffilib.dll", EntryPoint = "rustffi_get_version_free")]
        public static extern void rustffi_get_version_free(string s);

    }
}
```

The memory of the string returned from `rustffi_get_version` is not managed by Rust anymore as `mem::forget` has been called. In C#, I want to call the get version function, get the string, and then pass it back to Rust for memory deallocation like below.

```
public class RustService
{
    public static string GetVersion()
    {
        string temp = RustFfiApi.rustffi_get_version();
        string ver = (string)temp.Clone();

        RustFfiApi.rustffi_get_version_free(temp);

        return ver ;
    }
}
```

But the C# program crashes when it runs `rustffi_get_version_free(temp)`. How to free the forgotten string memory in C#? What should be passed back to Rust for deallocation?

Instead of defining `string` as the argument in the C# extern, I changed it to `pointer`.

```
[DllImport("rustffilib.dll", EntryPoint = "rustffi_get_version")]
public static extern System.IntPtr rustffi_get_version();

[DllImport("rustffilib.dll", EntryPoint = "rustffi_get_version_free")]
public static extern void rustffi_get_version_free(System.IntPtr s);
```

```
public static string GetVersion()
{
    System.IntPtr tempPointer = RustFfiApi.rustffi_get_version();
    string tempString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(tempPointer);

    string ver = (string)tempString.Clone();

    RustFfiApi.rustffi_get_version_free(tempPointer);

    return ver ;
}
```

The `IntPtr` from `rustffi_get_version` can be successfully converted to a C# managed string type. `tempString` and `ver` are good.

When `rustffi_get_version_free(tempPointer)` runs, it throws an exception saying **stack unbalanced**:

> A call to PInvoke function 'rustFfiLibrary!rustFfiLibrary.RustFfiApi::rustffi_get_version_free' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

`sizeof(IntPtr)` and `sizeof(char *)` are both 4 on my system. Plus, `IntPtr` works for return value; why doesn't it work as an input parameter?

Comment: The string you're returning will be a managed string once it gets into .NET land ... and therefore you can't just pass a pointer to it back to Rust because the .NET garbage collector may move it. I am wondering whether you'll need to add the `MarshalAs` attribute to help with this... unfortunately I can't test it right now (and I haven't done any C#->Rust interop yet!).

Comment: @simon, yes, that's what i think. So, do you think i should change the interface function in C# to [DllImport("rustffilib.dll", EntryPoint = "rustffi_get_version")]
        public static extern const char* rustffi_get_version(); ? Then I do the explicit conversion of char* to string myself

Comment: That is certainly an option worth exploring anyway.

Comment: @tried, but get another error. I edit the question to include the new information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`extern "C" fn` in Rust means the function uses the C calling convention.
C# expects P/Invoke functions to use the stdcall calling convention by default.

You can tell C# to use the C calling convention:

`[DllImport("rustffilib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

Alternatively, you could use `extern "stdcall" fn` on the Rust side.